# What are the negative traits that Red Talon Recruits have post-nerf

Tags: state-of-decay-2

After the Daybreak DLC, Undead Labs addressed the overpowered Red Talon Recruits by giving them negative traits that match their "profession".

I noticed this only recently because i had always played with my pre-nerf community. I recruited a hacker and she had +1 food consumtion on top of "wastes food sometimes". I got a demolitions expert who had +1 bed consumption and +2 zed threat.

What are all the negative points that the Red Talon recruits now come with?

1. Hacking

   - +1 Food consumption
2. Demolition

   - +1 Bed consumption
   - +2 Zed Threat (noise)
3. Infrastructure
4. Foraging
5. Gut Packing
6. Fortifications
7. Combat Medicine

   - +50% Fatigue Severity
8. Mobile Operations
9. Logistics
10. Firearms Maintenance

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a document](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uYu6VAC-M439uUhZNiEpCQKee0n7nMdkgByBY-UFLW8/edit#gid=0) which lists possible Red Talon operative traits - both positive and negative. The document also includes the trait's flavortext.

Most traits impact shooting skills and storage capactity. Here they are:

---

From an Armoured Unit

Pacifying the frontier is a lot easier with an inch of steel between you and the zombies

+5 Max Fuel Storage
-1 Labor
Sometimes wastes fuel

---

Red Talon Basic Training

The first few weks in Red Talon is hell, but you come out the other end ready for anything.

+30 Max Stamina

---

Combat Medic

I know how to treat common injuries in the field, though some people say I overmedicate

+5 Max Meds Storage
+50% Fatigue Severity
Sometimes wastes medicine

---

Demolitionist

I was the one who set the charges while everyone else ran for cover

+5 Max Ammo Storage
+5 Max Fuel Storage
+2 Zombie Threat
+1 Bed Used
Sometimes wastes ammo

---

Firearms Enthusiast

Your weapon is the only thing between you and certain death. You have to take care of it.

+5 Max Ammo Storage
+2 Zombie Threat
Sometimes wastes ammo

---

Forager

I know how to keep the squad going when the supply lines run dry.

+5 Max Food Storage
-1 Labor
Sometimes wastes medicine

---

Comms Engineer

With Red Talon, I worked on systems way ahead of what you have. So where do you keep the snacks?

+5 Max Food Storage
Sometimes wastes food
+100% Food Consumed Per Day

---

Drew Desk Duty

It turns out that Red Talon needs clerks, too. Lucky for me

+25% Fatigue Severity

---

Combat Ready

Let the zeds get close to me. See what happens.

+50% Fighting Experience Rate

---

Front Line Experience

I've been on the real frontier. It's a constant siege, day in and day out.

-40% Fatigue Severity

---

Diehard Veteran

I've got feral blood in my veins. Nothing can stop me.

-40% Injury Severity
+100% Infection Resistance

---

Facilities Engineer

You want to live somewhere long-term, you going to need an infrastructure.

+5 Max Materials Storage
+5 Max Fuel Storage
-30% Facility Action Speed
Sometimes wastes materials

---

Vigil Guard

I stood watch alone at a critical outpost for months. Ran out of room for notches on my rifle.

-1 Beds Used
-40% Fatigue Severity

---

Worked as a Pioneer

We were sent into newly cleared territory to build walls and prevent the zeds from coming back.

+5 Max Materials Storage
-20% Influence Gained
Sometimes wastes materials

---

Quartermaster

I know how to keep everything in order. Leave shit lying around, and you'll be hearing from me.

+5 Max Materials Storage
+5 Max Fuel Storage
+5 Max Ammo Storage
+2 Beds Used

---

Cooked for the Squad

Red Talon doesn't have a lot of full-time cooks, but when you're good, you get the job.

+5 Max Food Storage
+50% Vulnerability to Blood Plague
Sometimes wastes food

---

Red Talon Operative

I've spent several lifetimes on the front lines of this fight, and I'm coming back for more.

-95% Durability Loss Per Hit (Melee)
-95% Durability Loss Per Shot (Guns)
+60 Max Carrying Capacity
-100% Fatigue Severity
-100% Experience Rate

---

Designated Grunt

They don't ask me where to go, they tell me.

-10% Standing Rewards

---

Officer Material

The brass think I could really be somebody if I prove myself here   "50% Wits Experience

+6 Morale

---

Former Squad Leader

At my last posting, I ran the place. I'm a fucking people person.

+10% Standing Reward

---

Consul Officer

I've been to a lot of communities like this on, making deals and spreading our message

+50% Standing Rewards

---

Red Talon Trader

I travel a route that lets me bolster the strength of external units prior to recruitment.

+45 Max Health
-40% Injury Severity

---

Skipped Boot Camp

A pre-existing injury kept me out of boot camp when I joined Red Talon.

+25% Injury Severity

---

Boot Camp Survivor

Red Talon's boot camp is way harder than anything the zombies ever put me through.

+20 Max Health

---

Cadet Instructor

I've run the gauntlet so many times, the new recruits' pain just makes me laugh.

+50% Cardio Experience Rate

---

Dead Zone Runner

I did a tour running supplies into areas where our vehicles and comms couldn't reach.

+10 Light Carrying Capacity

---

Trained off the Grid

We had no gear, no bullets, and worst of all nothing to eat. I think I'm still hungry.

+50% Food Consumed Per Day

---

Practices at the Range

Being good isn't enough. You need a headshot every time.

+50% Shooting Experience Rate

---

Golden Eagle Marksman

Most of the shooters I know earned the same badge. The ones who didn't aren't with us anymore.

+20 Max Stamina

---

Red Talon Contractor

The folks around here look at me funny sometimes. Respect works both ways.

Irritable towards other people
-66% Standing Rewards"